# Web API - Controller Design

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API project that currently has a ServicesController. I get the list of services, for a server, by making this call:

```
$http.get(rootWebApiUrl + '/api/services/' + server)
```

The ServicesController has this signature:

```
public IEnumerable<FirstSolarService> Get(string id)
```

Now I want to make two more calls.

1. Get the Windows folders within the path for the service itself.
2. After the user selects a folder in #1, show the DLLs in that folder.

I have a choice to make as far as my Web API controllers go. Do I put this all in the ServicesController, or should I create separate controllers for each type of object I'm returning? If the latter, then I would create these two controllers:

1. FoldersController
2. FilesController

But what's awkward about that (maybe) is that I'd call each of those by passing in something other than the ID of the folder or file. To get folders, I'd pass in the service name. To get files, I'd pass in the path of the service. Is that the way it is supposed to be done? I'd just like to do this the correct way.

Comment: I don't think you should split it up into multiple controllers, unless they each are going to have considerable functionality (or Folders and Files are real domain objects/repository entities). As you may know, you are not limited to the `Get`/`Post`/`Put`/`Delete` convention for method names in WebAPIs. You can specify the action name if you want. For example, if you wanted a `Folders` method, you could add one (i.e. `[HttpGet] public ReturnType Folders(string serviceName)`) for which your URL would be `'/api/services/folders/' + server`.

Comment: Ahhh, good to know. So then I would just need to create a route in my RouteConfig and that should work. Philosophically, is it right to return folders from a services controller?

Comment: You probably don't even need to create a route -- the default one incorporates an `{action}` component. Philosophically, I would ask: are services composed of folders? Can folders exists without services? If folders depend on services, then I think it's ok to include that functionality in the services controller. If they don't, then split up the controllers based on functionality.

Comment: These comments are a good answer. If you'd like to paste them into an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: I have written an answer, but understand that questions like this are kind of broad and attract opinionated answers (which mine is), and it may eventually be closed.

Comment: Whatever. ;) At least I got what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you should split it up into multiple controllers, unless they each are going to each have considerable functionality, or if Folders and Files are real domain objects/repository entities.

As you may know, you are not limited to the `Get`/`Post`/`Put`/`Delete` convention for method names in WebAPIs. You can specify the action name if you want. For example, if you wanted a `Folders` method, you could add one:

```
[HttpGet] 
public ReturnType Folders(string serviceName)
{
}
```

Your API URL for the above would be `'/api/services/folders/' + server`.

You don't need to create a custom route -- the default one incorporates an `{action}` component. Philosophically, I would ask yourself: are services composed of folders? Can folders exists without services? If folders depend on services, then I think it's ok to include that functionality in the services controller. If they don't, then split up the controllers based on functionality.